# Make customised window Frame in java

Tags: java, window, frame

I have been wondering how it would be possible to create a `customized` window in java, like changing the position of the `maximize, minimize and close buttons` and changing the way they look as well. I have made a lot of search on the internet for a long time now, but the best I have come up with is using third party software, i would like to perform this operation myself, so am here asking for help as to how to go about it, I would appreciate all help.

Comment: SWT, AWT, Swing, Java-FX..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your JFrame frameless and than you can draw your own customized frame.

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Maybe this link is helpful
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: I tried that some time ago, the problem I had was that I was unable to place a JMenuBar in the proper place

Answer (score 0):

```
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
Frame.setUndecorated(true);
```